# rails paperclip - error processing thumbnail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, paperclip

I am running Rails 3.2.8 with Paperclip 3.3.0 on a Windows 7 machine. I am getting the following error when I try to upload an image named "2012-10-26_17.49.13.png": `Image There was an error processing the thumbnail for 2012-10-26_17.49.1320121027-1196-l5ejgs`

The filename may not be important, but I want to point out that most of the questions I find related to this say `error processing the thumbnail for stream` instead. No 'stream' on my error. The end of the filename changes randomly each time I try to upload (Paperclip doing some collision avoidance I assume).

The image field is set up in the model like this:

```
has_attached_file :image, :path => ":rails_root/public/images/:hash_:style.:extension", :url => "/images/:hash_:style.:extension", :hash_secret => "sometext", :default_url => "", :styles => { :thumb => "100x100#" }
validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => ['image/jpeg','image/jpg','image/pjpeg','image/png','image/x-png','image/gif']
```

The `has_attached_file` is using `:hash` at the moment, but I also tried with `:basefilename` or whatever it was and that didn't affect the results. The `:thumb` style has been tried as `"100x100>"` as well.

The field is like this in `_form.html.erb`:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :image %><br />
  <%= f.file_field :image %>
</div>
```

And the controller has nothing special in it regarding `:image` because Paperclip seems to take care of everything for me. At least, that's what I gathered from looking at example code.

I think it might be a problem with ImageMagick. Some of the solutions I found for this error involved the installation location of ImageMagick. I moved mine to C:/ImageMagick6, updated my system path, and added the following lines to development.rb:

```
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "C:/ImageMagick6"
Paperclip.options[:swallow_stderr] = false
Paperclip.options[:whiny_thumbnails] = true
```

I'm not entirely sure if the latter two are needed, but I saw them suggested. Didn't notice any changes from including them. If I open a command prompt, I can access the ImageMagick commands, so the path should be correct.

I also tried to run this with the `:styles` removed, which allowed me to upload the original image file. I really want the thumbnails for my site, though.

So, what have I missed that is keeping this from working?

Answer (score 1):

Despite having added `Paperclip.options[:command_path] = 'C:/progra~2/imagem~1.0-q'` to my config/environments/development.rb file, I had to add `C:/progra~2/imagem~1.0-q` before `%SystemRoot%\system32` in the environment path.

I confirmed this by revising the environment path back and forth a few times.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use Paperclip you need ImageMagick library installed.

[ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) provides two executables that are required by Paperclip: `identify` to *identify* the image format and `convert` that process the original image and generate the desired formats.

Now, ImageMagick does not come by default with Windows, so you need to install it manually.

Later, you will require to tell Paperclip where it will find the ImageMagick executables, which is all documented in [Paperclip README](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#image-processor)

Please note that if you don't set `Paperclip.options[:command_path]` to the PATH where ImageMagick was installed, Paperclip will incorrectly attempt to use Windows' `convert` executable, which is a Filesystem conversion utility and not meant to process images.

I believe that is the error you're currently receiving about generating the thumbnails.

Hope that helps.

Comment: ImageMagick is installed, and I did set the `:command_path` to my ImageMagick install path, but that didn't fix anything.

Comment: Then you need to ensure ImageMagick is **first** in the `PATH` instead of Windows one:

    `SET PATH=C:\ImageMagick;%PATH%`

That way `convert` being used is the one from ImageMagick.

Answer (score 0):

You might try using ImageMagick directly via the command line to manipulate an image. At the very least, this should confirm whether or not there's an issue with your ImageMagick installation.

Comment: The command line worked, and I ended up executing the thumbnail conversion manually during the upload process. It feels like a work-around, but it'll do until I figure out why my Paperclip path doesn't work. Thanks.

Comment: My mistake; it's not working. I am generating the command in my controller, trying to execute it via `shell` or backticks, and getting nothing. However, if I copy-paste the exact same command into my own command prompt and run it, it works.

Comment: Sounds like a command path issue. Are you using a relative or absolute filepath?